# Will a post on arXiv as a high school sophomore hurt my future academic life?

Tags: mathematics, arxiv, independent-researcher

I am a high school sophomore student who is very passionate about the subject of number theory and college level calculus. However, I am currently only in the high school class of precalculus/trig. The paper contains material beyond high school calculus, but am afraid that it would not be good enough for an actual arXiv paper.  Here are a few important facts to consider about my particular situation.

- (The math side) The proof is basically a non-summation proof of an inequality between an integral and a constant. By "non-summation" I mean like, if you have a sum of infinite terms, you are not allowed to approximate using 1000000 terms or whatever. This implies more strategic methods, no use of any obvious approximation methods like trap rule, **and most importantly, in my opinion,  why I feel it good enough.**
- I feel that this is not necessarily good enough for arXiv because I am not proving some general result, have 0 co-authors, and very limited assistance on the subject.
- I currently have no people to endorse, but quite confident I can achieve one (connections).
- If this is too low level, I am afraid that this might mar writing papers in the future, my credibility, etc.
- I have an unused arXiv account, which I doubt will be harmful (side question: will it?)

But, Ok, let's assume that I manage to pull this off during the summer. Assuming the paper is written fair enough, but about the content I am talking about, would writing the paper hurt my academic life down the road?

Comment: Oh, also, my Arx account is "independent researcher" currently, which I forgot to mention. Can this be changed?

Comment: Have you shown your work to any mathematicians?

Comment: I can't help but notice that you have given several points against posting a paper on the arxiv but not a single point in favor.  I honestly don't see why this is something a high school student needs to worry about, in roughly the same way that you don't have to worry about whether to get a mortgage or what kind of retirement plan to choose.  You are not a professional mathematician trying to advance your career...and it doesn't make sense (to me, a professional mathematician) that you would want to act like one at the moment.  That can happen 10 years later if you are still interested.

Comment: geometrikal I am planning to. What is nice is that my current teacher is a mathematician, and I will show it to her. (Actual mathatician) as to Pete L. Clark, I am interested for needless to say a stupid reason: I want to share my ideas on a formal level. Like previously stated, I am just very interested in math.

Comment: @AAron: There are many platforms for sharing your ideas: you could make a blog, for instance.  The arxiv is for *preprints*, i.e., advance copies of papers to be published in research journals.  It's great that you're interested in math: since you are now taking precalculus, you have essentially all of your mathematical life ahead of you.  You should keep learning and reading about math, and if you want to do math over the summer you should attend a program surrounded by other people who are interested in and talented at math (there are many such programs)....

Comment: ....Isn't it true that even if you've done something already that might be novel and publishable in some form, whatever you'll do 1,2,3,4,...years from now will necessarily be much better?  If so, why the rush to insert yourself in a professional forum when you yourself have already expressed the worry that this could impede your future professional life?

Comment: ...  In summary: you are a 14-16 year old who is really interested in mathematics and is probably very talented at it.  Why try to impersonate a 25-30 year old who feels pressured to publish something of relatively little value?  Being a great teenager is better -- and easier, and more appropriate, and more fun -- than being a subpar professional.

Comment: @Pete You make an extremely excellent point, and I will definitely follow it. Thank you.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Can you please convert these comments into an answer that I can vote for?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Can you please turn your comments into an answer, so that I can vote for it?

Comment: Keep in mind that posting to arXiv is not completely open. If you don't have the proper institutional affiliation (and occasionally even if you do) you'll be required to get an endorsement before you can post. If you are able to secure an endorsement with the paper then the odds that it is embarrassing are rather lower than otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest looking into publications that specifically target high school or undergraduate students. An example, but one that unfortunately no longer exists, is *The Mathematics Student Journal* ([sample issue from 1971](http://www.mrbottles.com/files/koutsoures-bakerTheorem.pdf)). A current one is [*Pi Mu Epsilon Journal*](http://www.pme-math.org/journal/submissions.html). An organization that I've been involved with both as a student (mid 1970s) and as a teacher (late 1990s) is [Mu Alpha Theta](http://www.mualphatheta.org/). These are USA based, but your teacher should know some appropriate for you.

Comment: [Involve](http://msp.org/involve/about/cover/cover.html), from the publishers of Geometry and Topology, is another good option for high school and college students with publishable results to consider.  Though notice that it requires significant oversight by a faculty member.

Comment: A downside of this route is that most of these journals (I think *Crux Mathematicorum* also belongs on that list) are not open-access, and not many people actually have access to them. This doesn't make publication wrong per se, but it might make it a worse option than posting on your website or on github/gitlab/... -- after all, you want people to read your work (people are increasingly hard to convince by cats in bags). You should definitely keep an accessible preprint around.

Comment: @darij grinberg: I just saw your comment (I've been away a couple of days), and I agree. In fact, I'm surprised they aren't open-access for the purpose of promoting the study of mathematics. I guess the needs of subscription money to keep the operations running prevent this.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest finding some friendly mathematician in the relevant field at a local college and ask them for their opinion on your work. Introduce yourself briefly in a mail, with an outline of the issue you would like to discuss and see whether you can arrange a meeting.

I do not second the suggestions to postpone publications because of youth. Not everybody is a Galois, but I know several students which at high-school age had publication-worthy results which they never published.

Rather, I suggest to subject OP's result to a reality check, to see whether it holds water and is new and sufficiently non-trivial/interesting. If it is, go ahead and publish.

Answer (score 4):

It is very difficult for a high school student to determine whether a result is original and interesting enough to experts to be publishable.  To make the point even clearer, when I was a highschool student I had a paper that I published (under the advice of a mathematician who suggested the problem to me) but I wasn't yet able to tell the difference between publishable and non-publishable results on my own!  Furthermore, the math that I did on my own (which I really enjoyed and was valuable for my mathematical development, and which even did ok in highschool science fairs) was not something publishable.

I haven't seen what you've written, but the odds are very low that it's publishable in a math journal.  But that's ok!  You can talk about it with your teacher and learn more stuff.  You could submit it to a highschool science fair.  You could talk about it with other highschoolers interested in math at a summer program or a forum like AoPS.  Smart highschool students thinking about math just aren't the main audience of research math journals or the arxiv, but that doesn't mean that the math that smart highschool students come up with doesn't have its own places.